# How can i open new layout when i click on current location in map in android

Tags: android, view, android-inflate, layout-inflater

i want to show new layout when i click on dispatchTap() method. How can i inflate new layout on click on current location ..
 This is my code

```
    public class CurrentLocationOverlay extends MyLocationOverlay {

    private Context mContext;
    private MapView mMapView;
    private Location mCurrentLocation;
    private MapController myMapController;
    double latitude, longitude;

    public CurrentLocationOverlay(Context context, MapView mapView) {
        super(context, mapView);
        mContext = context;
        mMapView = mapView;
    }

    @Override
    protected boolean dispatchTap() {
        // TODO handle a tap on "my location point", eg. display an option to
        // send SMS, make a call, add a picture to current location point.

            Toast.makeText(mContext, "Suppressing data readout", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

        return true;
    }
     /*LayoutInflater layoutInflater = (LayoutInflater) 
    mContext.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
LayoutParams lp = new MapView.LayoutParams(ViewGroup.LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT, ViewGroup.LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT, p, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
LinearLayout view = (LinearLayout)inflater.inflate(R.layout.map_overlay, null);
*/

}![enter image description here][1]
```

Answer (score 0):

Use ViewFlipper.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ViewFlipper xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/vf"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent" >

    <include android:id="@+id/main1" layout="@layout/main1" />
    <include android:id="@+id/main2" layout="@layout/main2" />

</ViewFlipper>
```

Assume main1.xml contains MapView and main2.xml contains layout you want to display when you click on current location on map.

```
ViewFlipper vf = (ViewFlipper)findViewById(R.id.vf);
```

Then use this code

```
@Override
protected boolean dispatchTap() {
    // TODO handle a tap on "my location point", eg. display an option to
    // send SMS, make a call, add a picture to current location point.
    vf.setDisplayChild(1); // to display main2.xml
        Toast.makeText(mContext, "Suppressing data readout", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

    return true;
}
```

I think it may help you.

Comment: no its not working.. i want to show the same effect, which is default in android Maps, click on current location show small layout.. please check your android Maps applcation. when we click on current location it show small layout.

Comment: I thought you have to show new layout which changes the current screen when you click on map. Now i understood what u are asking. I think with Map Overlay we may get same effect as in **Maps** application. try it once. I will also check. Thanks for comment. Bye

Comment: thanks for helping me... But what i want u understand now.. i think it will possible only with MyLocationOverlay. which handle the current location Click event.. As Mention the comment.

Answer (score 0):

See the below links, it may help you

[Discussion about Adding Layout as Overlay to Map](http://groups.google.com/group/android-developers/browse_thread/thread/17b182a281dd15cb#)

[Google Maps Driving Directions and Overlay](http://www.anddev.org/post3452.html#p3452)